# OpenWrt luci web interface logo picture and modify strings

Tags: string, openwrt

I am trying to modify the web interface of bootstrap theme in OpenWrt's luci web interface and i managed to change colors and some simple things but i cannot find how to change the names of the tabs (for example instead of "status" to write "status11111"). Also i wanted to add a logo picture on the top of the page and i managed to add it for the login page and also it appears on the default main page after the login but then if I swap to any tab the picture appears like crashed or missing (see the image bellow) and the link becomes like this `"/cgi-bin/luci/;stok=96c966ea63a7913b6c02fc09c7862d77/admin/status/overview"`.

My 2 questions are: how can I change the names of the tabs and how can I add a logo picture on the top of the page so it can appear to every tab? What files do I have to modify?

[image: Image of a web UI]

Comment: wow how did you get the username Bill when you only signed up a few days ago???

Answer (score 3):

For question #1 "how to change the names of the tabs", you want to look in /usr/lib/lua/luci/controllers/admin

There will be a number of files including "index.lua", "status.lua", "network.lua", etc. If, for example, you wanted to change the name of the status tab from "Status" to "New Status Tab Name", you would go into status.lua and find the line:

```
entry({"admin", "status"}, alias("admin", "status", "overview"), _("Status"), 20).index = true
```

and replace it with:

```
entry({"admin", "status"}, alias("admin", "status", "overview"), _("New Status Tab Name"), 20).index = true
```

For question #2, what exactly did you edit when you added the image?

Comment: thank you for your answer! Sorry that i didnt answer since this time but i was busy with another project. So here i am back to OpenWrt.

Question #1: I tried your example but unfortunately nothing changed for me :/ Should i also change something else? UPDATE: Finally it worked after a reboot to the board! Thanks!

Question #2: To add a picture I edited the header.htm of the template and i added this:

<body> <img src="../luci-static/resources/icons/test.png" alt="test" /> </body>

Comment: To avoid having to restart you can also try /etc/init.d/network restart or even better would be /etc/init.d/uhttpd restart (would allow you to stay connected to the device).

For question #2: I wouldn't use a relative path like that. I would probably try something like <img src="<%=media%>/resources/icons/test.png" />

Definitely read: 
http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/ThemesHowTo